# Converting SHP UTM to decimal lat/long

Tags: python, pyqgis, polygon, latitude-longitude, utm

I am trying to compare a list of lat/long to a shapefile and see which points are in or out of the polygon. I have discovered my shapefile is seemingly giving points in a UTM format. Below are some of the points in it, they should be in and around Chico, Ca / Paradise , CA area .

How do I convert these in Python to lat long?

I have used this site to help get this far, but these have negative UTMs so I am confused.

```
(-132880.64330000058, 206974.35539999977), 
(-133023.45749999955, 207491.3945000004), 
(-133151.86959999986, 207716.73259999976)
(-133028.29309999943, 206412.34610000066), 
(-133026.2402999997, 206414.30939999968), 
(-133023.83819999918, 206416.1897)
```

Comment: Negative UTM values are valid (albeit out of zone)

Answer (score 2):

Those aren't UTM, they look like California Albers. You should confirm with your data source which datum it is, but for this example let's assume it's [NAD83 California Albers](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3310/) aka EPSG:3310.

To convert the points in Python you can use [pyproj](https://pypi.org/project/pyproj/):

```
import pyproj

input = (-132880.64330000058, 206974.35539999977)

# set up the source projection, EPSG:3310 CA Albers
src_proj = pypoj.Proj(init='EPSG:3310')

# set up the target projection, EPSG:4326 WGS84 Geographic
dest_proj = pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:4326')

lon,lat = pyproj.transform(src_proj, dest_proj, *input)
```

Output:

```
>>> lon
-121.55409799333238
>>> lat
39.868818217594495
```